# How to get the selected columns tables in an inner join in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my select query with the inner join and the values that I want to select.

```
$user_reservation = DB::table('users')
            ->join('reservations', 'users.id', '=', 'reservations.users_id')
            ->select('users.id', 'reservations.id as res_id')
            ->get();
```

I need the **res_id** from the **$user_reservation** variable to be able to filter a result. Thank you

```
$reserved_rooms = $rr_model->where('reservation_id', '=', $user_reservation->res_id)->get();
```

Comment: Receiving any error?

Comment: Yes.  here is the error "**Property [res_id] does not exist on this collection instance.**"

Comment: You should edit your question and put additional information there, because its more likely to be read there than in comment

Answer (score 3):

It means you are receiving a collection, not an object because you are using `->get();`. You need to loop through the collection.

```
foreach($user_reservation as $reservation) {
    $reserved_rooms = $rr_model->where('reservation_id', '=', $reservation->res_id)->get();
}
```

But if you only want one instance of `$user_reservation` change your get() to first();

```
$user_reservation = DB::table('users')
->join('reservations', 'users.id', '=', 'reservations.users_id')
->select('users.id', 'reservations.id as res_id')
->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the relationship in your models:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

Define in your model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}
```

or

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Check the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships